# how to show only one notification at a time for android application

Tags: android, notifications

I use the following code to show the notifications

```
private void SendNotification(String notificationTitle, String notificationMessage) 
{
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
android.app.Notification notification = new android.app.Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, notificationMessage,
        System.currentTimeMillis());

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra("notif_id", "5100");

//Setting the single top property of the notification and intent.
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS; 
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(MainActivity.this, notificationTitle, notificationMessage, pendingIntent);
notificationManager.notify((int)System.currentTimeMillis(), notification);
}
```

Each time a new notification comes, the previous one should be removed and the new one should be shown.

Any clues will be helpful.

Thanx in advance

o.

Comment: To cancel the previous one(if exists), PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT), to replace the extra only PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Comment: AlexBcn, tried both options, none of them removed the previous messages. thanks for responding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one way that you should clear all Notification of your Application before you post a newer one. 
Give it a shot like,

```
notificationManager.cancelAll();
```

To clear a particular Notification you can do it like,

```
notificationManager.cancel(notification_id);
```

Comment: this solves it, thanx hopetribe, but just want to know if there is any option to do this using only flags.

Answer (score 6):

You are generatting a notification with different id each time (System.currentTimeMillis()), change it for a single ID.

`notificationManager.notify(0, notification);`

> Post a notification to be shown in the status bar. If a notification with the same id has already been posted by your application and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information.

[NotificationManager.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29)

Comment: Don't forget to cast System.currentTimeMillis() to int.